# Nodejs loop through response data from request

Tags: node.js, loops, asynchronous

The below data is returned from the `request()` library.

```
var data = [{
    service: "trains",
    ...
}, {
    service: "buses",
    ...
}]
```

I have the following code on a NodeJS application.

```
request(options)
.then(data => {
    data.forEach(record => {
        if (record.service !== 'buses') {
            return next('You do not have permission to access buses.')
        }
        return next()
    })
})
.catch(err => next(err))
```

So when this code runs on Node it always evaluates to false? This is odd to me because running this without the request and just using the raw response directly seems to work ok? I guess this is an issue with async behavior?

Comment: It seems next method is called more than one. What exactly evaluates to false?

Comment: yes, what evaluates to false. Besides, why are you doing return next() if you want to go through every element

Comment: Also you can avoid forEach loop with Array.some method. One posible fix: request(options).then(data=>data.some() ? next('error') : next()).catch(...)

Comment: It seems like you are returning next to proceed to the next .then, no? This would make you return the permission error and not even check against the 'buses' service. What exactly is it you are trying to accomplish with this promise?

Comment: Apologies, the data comes from a userId which I am checking to make sure the buses service exists. Otherwise, they are forbidden.

Comment: I guess from the comments here, I would like an explanation of how to implement this correctly rather than an answer.

Comment: the request will fetch complete JSON data and put it in `data`, irrespective of any async behavior.

Comment: @Nivesh Thank you, however there seems to be an issue when I try to loop through this data.

Answer (score 3):

You're looping through all the elements of the array, so if the first element does not match 'buses', it will result in 'You do not have permission to acces buses'.

I think what you're looking for is a method to check if an element exists in an array. In your case something like `Array.filter`:

```
.then(data => {
    if (data.filter(el => el.service === 'buses').length === 0) {
        return next('You do not have permission to access buses.');
    }
    return next();
})
```